# Twilio Simple Gather Action

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to do a simple  flow with twiml.
example

when the user press 1
play some text
if press 2
play other some text

the problem is that i can not find the way without using the uri action and exposing a new url to only retrieve a say with the speach.

Is it any other way to do something link that without using urls and new endpoints???

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to do the above using Twilio Studio, give it a go, it is all Serverless and elastic.

[Twilio Studio](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqrz4nXepkz5OwmqMONVJGBBa7grym6jx)

Comment: yes, I know with Studio it is easier, but I can not use it. Thanks

Comment: Understood, the Gather action URL is required to accept the Digits parameter via a GET/POST. So I assume Twilio Functions is also not an option?